# Terminal piping misunderestanding

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Folks I have a few questions around this command:

```
 echo 'cat //item/*[local-name()="id"]/text()' | xmllint --shell test.xml | sed '1 d;$ d;/^ -------$/ d' | sort | uniq --repeated
```

I thought command piping works from left to right. I'm confused around the `cat` command being used on nothing (`cat` command I've seen is usually used with a file example, `cat test.xml`).

Also, I'm not entirely sure what `cat //item/*[local-name()="id"]/text()` is doing, could someone explain? I know it's basically doing a cat against a XPath pattern but, it looks confusing especially with the other pipes and the XPath is going against nothing (again, it is normally used with a file such as xml, html, etc).

I'm basically new to `sed` command, could someone also explain what this means `sed '1 d;$ d;/^ -------$/ d'`.

Thanks.

Comment: This really isn't a system administration question.  I've voted to migrate it over to Unix&Linux.

Comment: At no point is `cat(1)` involved in the above code; see the `xmllint(1)` docs for details on its shell mode, which offers a shell-like interface to use common unix command names while rolling around in some XML document.